# Django / Gunicorn with Nginx reverse proxy - Wrong redirect to base path

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I have a Django app successfully running with Gunicorn/Uvicorn, under a subpath of my domain (example.com/myapp).

The Nginx vhost looks like this:

```
server {

    server_name example.com;

    location /myapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp_gunicorn/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /myapp/static/ {
        alias /home/www/myapp/static/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

upstream myapp_gunicorn {
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here is the systemd service with the start command of Gunicorn:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/www/myapp
ExecStart=/home/venvs/myapp/bin/gunicorn myapp.asgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8002 -w 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --log-file /home/www/myapp.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reading on [SO about Django in subfolder with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855488/django-in-sub-directory), I added the following settings to my Django settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/myapp'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
# To make Django trusts the https from the Nginx proxy
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

I can successfully access my app and its subpaths like https://example.com/myapp/endpoint and the Django admin page https://example.com/myapp/admin (successfully rewritten as https://example.com/myapp/admin/login/?next=/admin/) for example.

**However, when clicking on the validation button Django admin page, I get wrongly redirected to the base path (https://example.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/).
Also, I get a 404 for all the static files, they are also served under the base path https://example.com/static/xxx instead of the subpath https://example.com/myapp/static/xxx, although I thought it was correctly setup in the vhost.**

I have been looking at similar issues on SO (including [this very similar one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056374/redirects-from-nginx-reverse-proxyed-django-asgi-server-going-to-wrong-subdirect)), but it didn't help me.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you tell your app what the base path is?

Comment: In the Django setting, I set the BASE_DIR constant: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`, which is the system bas path of the app. By I'm not sure that's what you're referring to?

Comment: But where did you tell it that the base of all your routes is `/myapp`?

Comment: Nowhere, but I thought Django was managing that on its own. Locally it works fine. Should I set the base route? How?

Comment: From what I understand, FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME setting is supposed to fill this role in this precise case. Looks very much like this (unresolved ) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103470/django-admin-force-script-name-login-redirects-incorrectly

Comment: FYI I gave up, didn't find a solution and it seems there are none according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103470/django-admin-force-script-name-login-redirects-incorrectly. So I created different vhosts and subdomains for each of my Python apps.